# Adding buttons to header using css

Tags: html, css

I want to add button to following header. It should have layout like

http://www.fullstopinteractive.com/

**Header CSS:**

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:100px 0 50px 0;
}

div#header {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    background-color: #800080;
}

div#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color: #800080;
}

 @media screen {
    body>div#header {
        position:fixed;
    }

    body>div#footer {
        position:fixed;
    }
}

* html body {
    overflow:hidden;
}

* html div#content {
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**CSS:**

```
#nav {
    float: right;
    padding: 42px 0 0 30px;
}

#nav li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}

#nav li a {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ccc;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius: 14px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#nav li a:hover, #nav li a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="header">  
  <ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">KPI</a></li>  
  </ul> </div>
```

But the button are not appearing as in website. How to achieve this?
[image]

**Chrome**:

[image]

Comment: Just as an observation, you're missing `-ms-transition` in your CSS. If you're going to use prefixes, use them all.

Comment: @JonathanSampson The problem here is the links does not appear centered in the header div

Comment: Hello you want to append a button there?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, HOME and KPI should be centered in the purple bar at the top?

Comment: @ShibinRagh yes the button needs to be within the header div

Comment: Okay, the elements ARE on the page, but you've made them the same color as the background, among other problems. I will post a fiddle in a moment to show some fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to center the links in the "navbar", you shouldn't be floating them or positioning them absolutely. Here's a fiddle that shows them centered:

http://jsfiddle.net/9vtB5/1/ -> **updated**

All I changed was the first two rules for `#nav`:

```
#nav {
    text-align:center;
}

#nav li {
    display:inline;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}
```

Comment: The links goes out of when I decrease header height.

Comment: Don't specify a height. Just use `overflow:auto; zoom: 1;` in the #header rule.

Comment: Thanks for refrence but why does the text start after some line space http://jsfiddle.net/9vtB5/3/ and the content overlaps the footer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav {
    text-align:center;

}

#nav li {display:inline-block;}
```